# Spring Boot with different security contexts

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have two `DispatcherServlet`s and I want to have different contexts for them. First servlet should be secured with spring security and second servlet should not use security at all.

I register servlets as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean FirstServletRegistration() {
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.register(FirstWebConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);
        dispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(
            dispatcherServlet, "/api/*"
        );

        registrationBean.setName("firstServlet");
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean SecondServletRegistration() {
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.register(SecondWebConfig.class);
        dispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(
            dispatcherServlet, "/*"
        );

        registrationBean.setName("secondServlet");
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

For each of the servlets, I set the context:

- ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableWebMvc
  @ComponentScan("com.example.app.controllers.first")
  public class FirstWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

      @Bean
      public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
          return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
      }
  }
  ```
- ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableWebMvc
  @ComponentScan("com.example.app.controllers.second")
  public class SecondWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  }
  ```

And I want to use `SecurityConfig` only for "firstServlet":

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, DataSource dataSource) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/api/login")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

So how can I exclude use of security for "secondServlet"?

Comment: You may need to exclude "SecurityAutoConfiguration.class" in the maion SpringBootApplication, and then not use EnableWebSecurity for the firstServlet. The security context will need to be configured manually for that servlet. However, I am not sure that using two different servlets is the best approach here. I recommend either allowing all unauthorized requests through for the path desired for the second servlet, or splitting the second servlet into it's own spring boot application. You may have no choice, so let me know and I'll help with an example either way.

Comment: Also, would you happen to have a public github repo for the code you've already included? I have some free time on my hand:)

Comment: @Pytry, thank you for your response! I tried to exclude `SecurityAutoConfiguration.class` and I got following exception: "Parameter 0 of method setObjectPostProcessor in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' that could not be found." 
Why do you not recommend to use two servlets?

Comment: Mostly because it's just a pain to configure. Since it is a "non-standard" approach, it breaks the "opinionated" autoconfiguration of Spring Boot. If all you want is to serve static content from a certain path (say, root context), then there are easier ways of doing that without breaking with opinion.

Comment: what's the main reason that you need to 2 separate dispatcher servlet within 1 spring-boot application?

Comment: @imarchuang, I'm new to Spring Boot, but in other web apps this is a standard approach - to separate different logical parts to different servlets. For example, one servlet returns static content, and other servlet is responsible for REST api. Is it normal to use such approach in Spring Boot or is it better to use multiple Spring Boot applications or something other?

Comment: @Shirru: there's no anti-pattern per si if you would like to use 2 dispatcher servlets within one application. However, it would incur a lot of extra configuration that you wouldn't have otherwise. The DispatcherServlet design in SpringMVC is a "Front Servlet" pattern, and it is meant to serve as a centralized "router" servlet to route all your requests to the respective endpoint (Controller in MVC). Of course, it serves more than just a router servlet, as it also does view resolution and content negotiation etc. As such, 2 DispatcherServlet does not make it better.

Comment: @Shirru: For you case, I would recommend you to use one DispatcherServlet within you application, and make the routing to "Static Content" vs "REST api" with naming convention in your URL. However, if you are working on an "Enterprise" level project, I would suggest you to segregate your "Static Content" to a different application, e.g., just deploy those static contents to a lightweight Apache Http server, whereas leave the Spring-boot application handle the dynamic REST api part.